# Total hours calculation

Tags: mysql

I have a table of times `Attendance` from where I want to generate the report to display Total Time Group by User and Day.

```
INPUT TABLE
0 = IN TIME
1 = OUT TIME
```

---

```
USERID CHECK TIME CHECK TYPE

1396 2022-05-30 08:40:47 0
1396 2022-05-30 09:21:40 1
```

Output required

```
USERID TOTAL TIME
1396 5
```

Comment: Calculate sum between timedifference between time and LAG(time) where type=out and LAG(type)=in.

Comment: Have you even tried anything????